# Multiple conditions in arm templates

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Is there any way of achieving this in an arm template? Where the condition has multiple parts?

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
      "name": "[variables('website_notProduction_config')]",
      "condition": "[not(parameters('is_Production')) and equals(parameters('is_Not_Development'), 'True')]",
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, you need to use the `and()` function for that:

```
"[and(not(something), equals(something))]"
```

reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-logical#and